# SELECT based on Multi result condition

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to execute the following SQL statement in PostgreSQL 9.2 but it fails with error:

```
SELECT "TrainingName" FROM "HSETrainingName" WHERE "ID" = 
SELECT "trainingID" FROM "HSEGroupedTraining" WHERE "groupID" =3
```

The second select statement returns more than one value. How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IN` construction:

```
SELECT "TrainingName" 
  FROM "HSETrainingName" 
 WHERE "ID" IN (SELECT "trainingID" 
                  FROM "HSEGroupedTraining" 
                 WHERE "groupID" = 3)
```

Comment: ... which PostgreSQL will likely transform to a join, which is the other way of formulating the query - an inner join between `HSETrainingName` and `HSEGroupedTraining`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Subquery along with IN:

```
SELECT "TrainingName" 
FROM "HSETrainingName" 
WHERE "ID" IN
(SELECT "trainingID" 
FROM "HSEGroupedTraining" 
WHERE "groupID" =3)
```